# Error executing a function in a AsyncTask doInBackground JsonParser/PHP

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

Ok, i find a lot of people with the same problem but i was not able to find a good answer yet.
I im doing a simple httprequest with JSON parser, but im getting this error:
12-13 17:11:35.406: E/AndroidRuntime(28346): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-13 17:11:35.406: E/AndroidRuntime(28346): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-13 17:11:35.406: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)

I am really lost. Anyone have an answer?

here is my code: 
Java: Main Ac.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


import com.exemple.beans.MesaBean;
import com.exemple.json.JSONParser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String ESTABELECIMENTO = "NossoBar";
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText numeroMesa;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Button criar;
    private static String url_create_product = "http://www.naga.net.br/android/beerapp/delete_product.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static Vector<MesaBean> mesas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        criar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncriar);
        numeroMesa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numeroMesa);
        if (mesas == null) {
            mesas = new Vector<MesaBean>();

        }

        criar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int numero = Integer.valueOf(numeroMesa.getText().toString());
                String senha = gerarsenha();
                int id = mesas.size()+1;
                String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat
                        .getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                MesaBean mb = new MesaBean();
                mb.setCriadoEm(currentDateTimeString);
                mb.setIdmesa(id);
                mb.setSenha(senha);
                mb.setMesa(numero);
                mesas.add(mb);
                String resp = ESTABELECIMENTO+numero+senha;

                new CreateNewProduct(resp).execute();



            }
        });


    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String resp;

        CreateNewProduct() {

        }

        public CreateNewProduct(String resp) {
            this.resp = resp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Postando comparação...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting JSON Object
            try {
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mesaconta", resp));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lalal", "lalal"));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    resp = "Sucess";

                } else {

                    resp = "Fail";
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class));
            }

            if (resp.equalsIgnoreCase("Sucess")) {

                // closing this screen
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ListaMesas.class));
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    private String gerarsenha() {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 9;

        Random r = new Random();
        Integer a = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Integer b = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Integer c = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Integer d = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Integer e = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Integer f = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

        String resp = a.toString() + b.toString() + c.toString() + d.toString()
                + e.toString() + f.toString();
        return resp;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

JsonParser:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

The code in PHP on the server allready works fine, im using it  in another program.
Can you help me?

Full tracktrace:

```
12-13 18:03:06.516: E/JSON Parser(31184): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of 
12-13 18:03:06.516: W/dalvikvm(31184): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a0b6f0)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at com.example.gerente2.MainActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:117)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at com.example.gerente2.MainActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-13 18:03:06.546: E/AndroidRuntime(31184):    ... 4 more
12-13 18:03:07.306: W/IMGSRV(31184): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 3355 handle: 0x866bf70 size: 540 x 888 fmt: 2 usage: 0x933
12-13 18:03:07.306: W/IMGSRV(31184): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 3356 handle: 0x86bfa60 size: 540 x 888 fmt: 2 usage: 0x933
12-13 18:03:07.316: W/IMGSRV(31184): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 3359 handle: 0x8649a10 size: 392 x 175 fmt: 1 usage: 0x933
12-13 18:03:07.316: W/IMGSRV(31184): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 3360 handle: 0x8669800 size: 392 x 175 fmt: 1 usage: 0x933
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184): Activity com.example.gerente2.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@211b52a0 that was originally added here
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.gerente2.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@211b52a0 that was originally added here
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:356)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:284)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at com.example.gerente2.MainActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:99)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at com.example.gerente2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3531)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4699)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
12-13 18:03:08.006: E/WindowManager(31184):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the string that you are receiving back from that server?  The

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1
```

Means you're getting an empty response back from the server.

Comment: ok, now the server is responding bur im getting this:

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: i dont know where to look for the error. My java code seems fine. The other erro was that my user have no permissions, but i already fixed. Now im lost igain